# A generalized randomized mean estimate based on the Chebyshev inequality

Tags: probability, estimation, monte-carlo

Let $X$ be a random variable that does not take on a single value with probability 1. Let “black-box" sample access to the random variable $X$ be given. Let $M_k$ be an upper bound on the $k$th central absolute moment of $X$, for $k>1$.

Suppose a probability $\delta$ and an error $\epsilon$ are user-specified. Is the mean $\mathbb{E}[X]$ within $\epsilon$ of the mean of $n$ i.i.d. samples, where—

$$n=\left\lceil\frac{M_k}{\delta\epsilon^k}\right\rceil,$$

with probability at least $1-\delta$?

If yes:

Let $f(x)$ be uniformly continuous on the real line. Let $m(\epsilon)$ be an inverse modulus of continuity of $f$, that is, a function that satisfies $|f(y)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|y-z|<m(\epsilon)$. Then is $f(\mathbb{E}[X])$ within $\epsilon$ of the mean of $f$ on $n$ i.i.d. samples, where—

$$n=\left\lceil\frac{M_k}{\delta(m(\epsilon))^k}\right\rceil,$$

with probability at least $1-\delta$?

A partial proof of the first question: $$\mathbb{P}(X\ge\epsilon) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{\epsilon} \tag{Markov's inequality}$$ $$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|^k\ge\epsilon^k) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|^k]}{\epsilon^k} \tag{Change of variables}$$ $$\mathbb{P}(|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|\ge\epsilon) \le \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|^k]}{\epsilon^k} \tag{Simplify}$$ This is already interesting; has the last inequality already appeared in a published work before?  I have found the case $k=4$ in Markowsky et al. 1978.

### Motivation

The idea for this comes from the Chebyshev inequality and also from the references below.

The answer to this question will help improve my [article on randomized estimation algorithms](https://github.com/peteroupc/peteroupc.github.io/blob/master/estimation.md). It was moved out of a more general question on [estimating $f(\mathbb{E}[X])$ with a guaranteed error performance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/522429/estimating-f-mathbbex-with-a-guaranteed-error-performance?noredirect=1#comment1020772_522429).

### References

- Hickernell, F.J., Jiang, L., et al., "Guaranteed Conservative Fixed Width Intervals via Monte Carlo Sampling", arXiv:1208.4318v3 [math.ST], 2012/2013.
- Kunsch, Robert J., Erich Novak, and Daniel Rudolf. "Solvable integration problems and optimal sample size selection." Journal of Complexity 53 (2019): 40-67.
- Markowsky, G., Carter, J. L., & Wegman, M. N., "Analysis of a universal class of hash functions", In Mathematical Foundations of Computer Science 1978. Springer, 1978.