# Estimate the mean of a normal distribution with bounded but unknown variance

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

Say we have a normal distribution with unknown mean and variance and we take $n$ samples from it. Then, the usual confidence interval for the mean uses the $t$-distribution. But if we know that the variance is less than, say, 100, can we use that knowledge to make a smaller confidence interval for the mean?

Comment: You may be able to get around the problem by adopting a Bayesian approach. You could assign (say) $\sigma^2 \sim U(0,100)$ and then assign a flat prior to $\mu$. However, I suspect the impact of any approach will depend on how close the true $\sigma^2$ is to the upper limit

Comment: What sample size?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517043/how-to-construct-a-confidence-interval-of-the-mean-when-the-distribution-is-unk ; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4158937/determine-sample-size-when-the-population-distribution-and-variance-is-unknown-i/4159582#4159582

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible, but the benefit may not be worth the effort.  A Wald confidence interval does not account for the sampling variability of the estimated standard error, essentially treating it as known.  Inverting this test produces a confidence interval very similar to inverting the t-interval.  Any interval you construct that accounts for the sampling variability of the standard error, while knowing that the unknown true population variance is less than 100, will be wider than a Wald interval and shorter than a t-interval.  Let me know if I have made any mistakes.